# Not getting mouseout event for div inside an iframe when browser window cuts off edge of div

Tags: javascript, iframe, mouseout

test.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>mouseout test</title>

<script type="text/javascript">

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    document.getElementById("a").addEventListener('mouseout', function() { 
            console.log("mouseout");
        });
    document.body.addEventListener('mouseout', function() { 
            console.log("bodymouseout");
        });
    });
</script>
<style>
#a{ border:1px solid black; width:300px; height: 300px;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="a">
        move mouse out of this div
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

testframe.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>mouseout test frame</title>
<style>
iframe 
{
    width: 330px;
    height: 330px;
}

#a{ border:1px solid green; width:350px; height: 350px;}

</style>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe src="test.html"/>
</body>
</html>
```

- When `testframe.html` is loaded in Chrome (on Windows), resize the browser to be narrow so that the right edge of the div is cut off.

  - Move the mouse out of the div off the right side.  No mouseout event.
- When browser window is big enough to show the whole div, mouseout fires when moving the mouse out of all sides of the div.
- When `test.html` is loaded directly in the browser, the mouseout event fires when moving the mouse out of all sides regardless of browser window size.

Works correctly in Firefox (unless someone can make the case that the Chrome behavior is correct).

Any suggestions for a workaround to detect when the mouse moves out of the div in this case?

I also tried adding the mouseout event handler to the document and window objects in the iframe, but no success.

Comment: This may be of assistance: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058085/iframe-onmouseout-capture

Comment: Thanks Stan.  I did see that question and tried putting the event handler on the body (see example above), but still no luck when the browser is sized to cut off the right edge of the div.  I am looking into adding event handler in parent window to catch the mouseout and then postMessage to child window.